# Generate TSV/CSV with multi-line cells that open in Numbers

Tags: numbers, csv

I want to programmatically generate tsv files with multi-line cells that stay preserved when opened in Numbers app.

What newline character to use to enable multi-line cells?

Comment: To your deleted answer (which wasn't an answer) try this in **Terminal**: `printf '"line one\nline two"\r\nanother line' > foobar.csv`

Comment: @user3439894: Yes this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is kind of standardized with [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). For multi-line fields the rules are

- MS-DOS-style lines that end with (CR/LF) characters (optional for the last line).
- Any field may be quoted (with double quotes).
- Fields containing a line-break, double-quote or commas should be quoted.
- If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote must be represented by two double-quote characters.

If this doesn't work with Numbers, you can also create a Numbers file, add some multi-line fields, export the file as CSV/TSV and verify the encoding/quoting used with TextEdit afterwards.

From the comment of [@user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894):

> When **Numbers** exports to **CSV** it uses **CR/LF** between *rows* but uses **LF** for multi-line *cells* and the *value* is in *double-quotes*.

Comment: When **Numbers** exports to **CSV** it uses **CR/LF** between _rows_ but uses **LF** for multi-line _cells_ and the _value_ is in _double-quotes_.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks, I've added this to the answer.

Comment: @nohillside: Works! For anyone trying please make sure there is no space between delimiter and double-quotes.